# Is there any way to replace the asset programatically?

Tags: plugin-development, assets, image, upload

In the CP, when we upload an image with a same name, craft will ask if we wanna keep both or replace.
So in plugin, is there any way to do the replace?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the scenario `SCENARIO_REPLACE` or `SCENARIO_CREATE` depending what you like to do

```PHP
$asset = new \craft\elements\Asset();
$asset->tempFilePath = $tmpFilePath;

$asset->setScenario(\craft\elements\Asset::SCENARIO_REPLACE);
```